# Excel If statesment. Logical test by "contains" value instead of "equals" or "does not equal" value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to run an **if statement** in which the "logical test" is whether or not a cell contains a value (or figure) somewhether in the cell, rather than whether it equals or does not equal a value. Example:

```
If(A1 (**contains**) ",", X, Y)
```

My goal is to return "X" if there is a comma anywhere in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",A1)),"Y","X")
```

or equivalently

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND(",",A1))),"X","Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of ISERROR and FIND to do contains:

=IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND("string that it should contain",A1)),True,False)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*,*")>0,"X","Y")
```